# What is the point of NFT vouchers?

Tags: mining, nft

NFT vouchers signed by an NFT image creator are a way to lazily mint NFTs but what real purposes do they serve?

Answer (score 1):

NFT vouchers are not signed by the user, but by the NFT creator, or at least by an address allowed to mint and should eventually adhere to [EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712).

The whole purpose is to allow *Lazy Minting* : minting on demand when users are buying the NFT. Users can redeem an NFT by providing the voucher they received and the redeem process will do the following at a high level :

- Check voucher validity
- Mint NFT to the voucher's address
- Transfer the NFT to the redeemer address

The main goal / purpose of this is to deport the minting cost to the user side, that way content creators don't need to mint X tokens beforehand, which can represent significant investments depending on the gas prices. Since the Voucher contains a minter's signature which should be checked at the `Check voucher validity` step, it's also a secure process.

The voucher can be time limited / bound to a specific buyer / etc...

I hope that answer's your question.

Comment: Then why create vouchers. Instead, you can allow "users" to upload their images to a website (stores images in a cloud). You can simply display those images. And when someone wants to buy an image it can be minted, send to the buyer and lastly, the payment can be recorded on the NFT image creators' balance (within the smart contract). This way, the content creator doesn't pay anything. I guess I am missing something in this approach. (btw. isn't this how Opensea handles lazy minting?)

Comment: I also changed the "user" to "NFT image creator" in my OP. Thanks for pointing to that...

Comment: The voucher is essentially a cryptographically signed agreement from the creator / minter  to mint a specific NFT.  Your example would probably work too for the prices, but the creator must have control over what is minted and what is not otherwise anyone could do it. You'd most probably fallback on something similar to a voucher to ensure such control. The signed voucher ensures both minting price for the user and minting rights to the creator if that makes things a bit more clear ? Plus it has the benefit of being 100% on chain.